# ugarchforecast returns values for incorrect date

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I'm trying to use the rugarch package in R to produce volatility and point (mean value) forecasts of monthly inflation rates in the US. I queried the time series data using the FRED API and fit a model with a GARCH(4,0) and ARMA(2,0) to the data. The time series runs from January 1948 to April 2023. I am trying to forecast 10 steps ahead (so through Feb. 2024) and also want to compute the 95% CI interval forecast.  The problem is that when I try to extract the sigma and mean values, the output returned treats the T+1, 2...,10 as being from "1972-06-22". This doesn't make sense because the last observation of the data is April 2023 and the rows of my tsibble object are in chronological order. Moreover, it should not be returning a YYYY-MM-DD because my data is at a monthly frequency.

Why is it returning the wrong date and what can I do about this?

```
# Get data and turn it into tsibble 
inflrt <- fredr(series_id = "CPIAUCSL",
                units = "pc1") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(month=yearmonth(date)) %>%
  select(month, value) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=month) 

# Specify model 
garch_inflrt <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(4,0)), 
                           mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(2,0), include.mean=TRUE),
                           distribution.model="sstd")

#Fit data to model 
fit_garch_inflrt <- ugarchfit(spec=garch_inflrt, data=inflrt$value)

#Check fit of model  
infocriteria(fit_garch_inflrt)

coef(fit_garch_inflrt) 

#Check squared residuals/variance
garch_inflrt_res <- (residuals(fit_garch_inflrt)^2)
res_var_inflrt <- garch_inflrt_res/fit_garch_inflrt@fit$var
tsdisplay(res_var_inflrt)
Box.test(res_var_inflrt) 

# Forecast
fc_inflrt <- ugarchforecast(fit_garch_inflrt, n.roll=0, out.sample=0)

#95% CI interval forecast for returns 

#check the sigma and fitted values
sigma(fc_inflrt)
fitted(fc_inflrt)
#Running both sigma() and fitted() returns a table in my console for T+1,...T+10 where the T indicated in the header is "1972-06-22 17:00:00."

fc_inflrt_ci = data.frame(sigma = sigma(fc_inflrt),
                         fitted_val = fitted(fc_inflrt)) %>%
  rename(sigma=1,
         fitted_val=2) %>%
  mutate(lower = fitted_val - (1.96*sigma),
         upper = fitted_val + (1.96*sigma))
fc_inflrt_ci
```